# Check which of an array value is also an object property

Tags: javascript

I have a object 'ecom' which will have a property that is one of `['detail','add','remove','checkout','purchase']`

I want to know which of the 5 potential properties the object has.

What is the shortest, cleanest way to get that?

Comment: Please post what you've tried that isn't working, so we have a specific idea of what sort of roadblock you're running into

Comment: What have you tried? Any code so far?

Comment: `your_array.filter(v => your_object[v] !== undefined)[0]` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `filter()` and `hasOwnProperty()`

```js
let arr = ['detail','add','remove','checkout','purchase'];
let obj = {detail:'val',add:0,purchase:33}


let res = arr.filter(x => obj.hasOwnProperty(x));
console.log(res)
```

#### Without arrow function

```js
let arr = ['detail','add','remove','checkout','purchase'];
let obj = {detail:'val',add:0,purchase:33}


let res = arr.filter(function(x){
    return obj.hasOwnProperty(x)     
}) 
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thanks this works in my console except I'm working in an environment (Google Tag Manager) that does not work with arrow function ```=>```. Any alternative?